# How to find if a record exist in PySpark in an efficient way?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Given a PySpark Dataframe I'd like to know if for a column `A` exists a value (e.g. `5`). The first approach would be to do something like

```
df.filter("A = 5")
```

but in this way the function would look for all the records that have that value, taking more time than expected. Instead if for example I know that I find the value in one of the first records I don't need to go ahead and continue iterating.

For example:

```
+---+
| A |
+---+
| 0 | 
| 5 |
| 1 |
| 9 |
| 1 |
| 4 |
| 1 |
...
| 5 |
| 1 |
```

and suppose that it contains for thousands of records, I'd like to have a quick result as the 2nd record is 5, no need to check for the whole DF (of course there's no guarantee of performance because I might be unlucky and 5 is only the last record, but if I can save resources would be great!).

Any idea on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

An approach might be with

```
df.filter("A = 5").head()
```

With some tests I spotted a noticeable difference in execution time and the Spark engine seems to return in this way only the first occurrence that satisfies the condition.

So if it returns `null` the record doesn't exist (it will have to iterate through all the Datframe obviously), otherwise a Row object will be returned.